# Guardar los valores para no perderlos al recargar la página

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que me cambia los colores de una celda, pero lo que busco es que no me borre los resultados al reiniciar la página, pues estoy haciendo una página para que los usuarios puedan marcar las horas que tienen disponibles semanalmente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function ilumina(celda){
    if (celda.style.backgroundColor=="yellow")
        {
        celda.style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
    else
        {
        celda.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        }
    }
  </SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si quieres que lo que esté marcado por un usuario sea visible para otros usuarios, necesitas mandar la información al backend para que se guarde y provea a otros usuarios

Comment: Has probado a guardarlo en localStorage ? así no necesitas usar ningún lenguaje de back-end y todo queda en el navegador.

Comment: disculpar, pero mi falta de conocimientos me impide hacer eso que me indicas, si podéis explicármelo mas detalladamente, gracias

Comment: Cuando abres el inspeccionador de código, te abren varias pestañas(consola, red, aplicación, etc). En la pestaña aplicación aparecen el localStorage y el sessionStorage, donde puedes guardar cualquier dato, el localStorage permanece aunque cierres la página, el sessionStorage al cerrar el navegador desaparece)

Comment: para agregar algo al local o session storage, solo tienes que escribir localStorage.setItem("nombre", valor); lo mismo para obtener el valor. localStorage.getItem("nombre"); o eliminar localStorage.removeItem("nombre"); o localStorage.clear(); que borra todo.

Comment: creo que no me sirve usar local Storage, pues solo me lo. guarda para mi en mi navegador, yo lo que necesito es que me lo guarde para que lo vean todos los usuarios

Comment: para eso vas a necesitar un backend y una bbdd

Comment: Gracias Suso, podrías ayudarme con el código que necesito ?

Answer (score 0):

he modificado un poco el código, por si alguien puede explicarme como guardar los datos para que la página sea visible a todos los usuarios web

```html
<html lang="es">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />

  <head>
   
    
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ilumina(celda){
     if (celda.style.backgroundColor=="yellow")
         {
         celda.style.backgroundColor="PeachPuff";
         }
     else
         {
         celda.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
         }
     }
   </SCRIPT>
  <table border="1" summary="Los grupos de música punk más famosos del Reino Unido">
    <caption>CLICK ON THE CELLS TO SELECT YOUR AVAILABLE HOURS</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Grupo</th>
        <th scope="col">Año de formación</th>
        <th scope="col">Número de álbumes</th>
        <th scope="col">Canción más conocida</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">LUNES</th>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">9-10 a.m</td>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">10-11 a.m</td>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">11-12 a.m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">MARTES</th>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">9-10 a.m</td>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">10-11 a.m</td>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">11-12 a.m</td>
      </tr>
  
        
  
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">MIERCOLES</th>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">9-10 a.m</td>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">10-11 a.m</td>
        <td bgcolor="PeachPuff" onclick="ilumina(this)">11-12 a.m</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  PULSE SOBRE LAS CELDAS PARA SELECCIONAR SUS HORAS DISPONIBLES
  </body>
  <meta>
</html>
```